# Isn't this a way users "Market themselves" with multiple SE accounts?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, astroturfing

Assuming a user has two accounts in SE (account A & B).

He asks a question using account A. Answers it using account B. It's not just answering, the answer is just "fantastic" - thus it has drawn votes from 15 - 30+. This is different from asking a question under one account and answering it using same account.

There is a scenario with pattern found within VBA tag.
When noticed, most of his questions are either duplicates or have been closed by community with closed line: "not clear, off topic" etc. 
The question and answer seem to have quite distinct same formatting.

Bottom line, it seems like the OP is trying to promote oneself within the SE. Isn't this defined as against SE moderator/review *rules*?

*Personally I benefit and enjoyed his answers though.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having multiple accounts is not categorically prohibited on SE, but there are rather strict criteria on what you can do with your accounts.

You are not allowed to circumvent *any* limit of the SE system, the only way to ensure this is for the accounts to never interact at all.

Self-answers are often viewed a bit more critical than regular answers by the community, so using a sock puppet likely has an effect on the amount of votes you'll receive. It is also fundamentally misleading, and for that reason not an allowed usage of multiple accounts.

If you suspect that two accounts belong to the same user, just flag for moderator attention and let them take a look at it.

Comment: Jargon 'sock-puppet'. I had forgotten that. It seems under sock-puppet keyword, there are quite a number of questions already asked - mostly similar to mine.